# How to apply column formatting in gspread-formatting

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-colaboratory, gspread

I am trying to apply column formatting while exporting the dataframe to google sheet with the help of gspread. I am using format_with_dataframe method but I am unsure on how to pass column-name & data types as part of column_formats attribute.

I have shared my code below.

```
from gspread_formatting import *
from gspread_formatting.dataframe import format_with_dataframe, BasicFormatter
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())

import pandas as pd

data = [['tom', 10.1123, 0.23], ['nick', 15.3445, 0.3224], ['juli', 14.12, 0.023], ['robert', 9.0809, 0.722]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'S-Mark', '%-Value'])

sh = gc.create("Test")
worksheet = gc.open("Test").worksheet("Sheet1")
set_with_dataframe(worksheet, df)

formatter = BasicFormatter(
    header_background_color=Color(0,0,0),
    header_text_color=Color(1,1,1),
    column_formats= {'S-Mark':'{:,.0f}'.format,'%-Value':'{:,.2f}'.format }
)

format_with_dataframe(worksheet, df, formatter, include_index=False, include_column_header=True)
```

I am sharing sample output as well

[image]

Comment: In your script, what is `'{:,.0f}'`? If it's the pattern of the number format, can you provide the sample output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: @Tanaike, I have added sample output. Issue is that, I am not sure - How to add arguments to column_formats attribute of BasicFormatter.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your showing image, I understood that `'{:,.0f}'` for `formatters={'cost': '{:,.0f}'.format}`. And, in your sample output situation, `index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` is used. But, the data of dataframe is only one column. So I cannot understand your goal. I apologize for this. Can you provide the detailed goal you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike, I have update the image now.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your updated question, I couldn't understand the sample output situation you expect.